# Why isn't the 'animation-delay' attribute working?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm currently trying to make the animation-delay attribute work on my JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/ACollinsTMCC/qpvq95ku/8/) for two separate classes so they appear to fade in after one another when hovering over the parent div (the red boxes), but it seems to be ignoring this. Here's my code:

CSS

```
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
25% { opacity: 0.25; }
50% { opacity: 0.5; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
0% { opacity: 0; }
25% { opacity: 0.25; }
50% { opacity: 0.5; }
75% { opacity: 0.75; }
100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.fadebox {
height:200px;
background:red;
}
.fadebox-child {
display:none;
opacity:0;
height:150px;
width:150px;
background:blue;
border-radius:100%;
margin: 10px auto;
}
.fadewrapper:hover>.fadebox-child {
display:block;
opacity:1;
-webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-name: fadeIn;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
animation-duration: 0.5s;   
}

.2 {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
animation-delay: 1.5s;}
.3 {
-webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
animation-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="fadewrapper text-center">
    <div class="fadebox">Digital</div>
    <div class="fadebox-child 1 text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
    <div class="fadebox-child 2 text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
    <div class="fadebox-child 3 text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="fadewrapper text-center">
    <div class="fadebox">Digital</div>
    <div class="fadebox-child text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
    <div class="fadebox-child text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
    <div class="fadebox-child text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="fadewrapper text-center">
    <div class="fadebox">Digital</div>
   <div class="fadebox-child text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
    <div class="fadebox-child text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
    <div class="fadebox-child text-center"><p><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Web Design</a></p></div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `2` is not a valid class name. Classes must start with a letter.

Comment: I have tried changing the classes to 'two' and 'three' but that just breaks the original fade in effect.